# Notification in android Wear

Tags: android, notifications

I want to show a simple notification on android wear then i want to give a action on tap on notification,i don't want to show any paging in notification.
I seen many examples but all are of paging, i just want to give a simple notification and want to handle on tap event.

Comment: Have you checked http://developer.android.com/training/wearables/notifications/creating.html ?

Comment: Yes I checked but the problem is, i dont want to use paging,I just want a simple plain notification and i want to handle onTap event on that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to change my resources to yours. `setContentAction(0)` is what you generally need.

```
 public void showNotification() {

    Intent eventIntent =  new Intent(context, GridCardsActivity.class);
    PendingIntent openAppIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 1, eventIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);


    Notification.Action openAction = new Notification.Action(R.drawable.logo_sm, "open", openAppIntent);
    Notification notification = new Notification.Builder(context)
            .setContentTitle(pulse.getName())
            .setContentText(pulse.getQuestion())
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.logo)
            .extend(new Notification.WearableExtender()
                            .addAction(openAction)
                            .setContentAction(0)
                            .setHintHideIcon(true)
                            .setBackground(bm)
            )

            .build();
    ((NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE))
            .notify((int) System.currentTimeMillis(), notification);
}
```

Comment: Hey Thanks!That's worked for me,But I already Did it by custom cards.